# How can I prove the eccentricity of a quadratic conic is invariant under bijective affine transformations?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, affine-geometry

I’m trying to prove that the eccentricity of a conic doesn’t change through BAT (bijective affine transformations). It seems pretty obvious to me that by translations and rotations it won’t change. I can’t use the determinant of the projective matrix of the conic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it because it's not true. Scaling $x$ by a factor of $2$ and leaving $y$ alone transforms a circle into an ellipse.

Comment: So how can I prove that a BAT takes a given conic to a conic of the same type (ellipse to ellipse, hyperbola to hyperbola, and parábola to parabola)

Comment: Note that @M.Navarro's comment-question above relates to [a previous question-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2968299/409). Answerers may wish to respond there.